# Spring boot Cacheable is not working after CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a token and i am storing validate state in database. If I call `checkTokenExistsThrowError` method its caching and no more calling inside of method because of Cacheable.

However, when I call `addTokenToBlacklist` method, it deletes the token from cache because its state updated to "invalid". After when I call `checkTokenExistsThrowError` method its not catching and running method inside everytime (i am using debug). Cache is broking.

```
  @Cacheable(key = "#token", value = "tokens")
  public void checkTokenExistsThrowError(String token) {
    var result = tokenRepository.findTokenByTokenAndValid(token, false).isPresent();
    if (result) {
      throw buildException(TOKEN_IS_NOT_VALID_EXCEPTION);
    }
  }

  @CacheEvict(key = "#token", value = "tokens")
  public void addTokenToBlacklist(String token) {
    Token tokenObj = new Token();
    tokenObj.setToken(token);
    tokenObj.setValid(false);
    tokenRepository.save(tokenObj);
  }
```

Pom.xml:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. `throw buildException(TOKEN_IS_NOT_VALID_EXCEPTION);` is blocking to @Cacheable annotation. I extracted throw exception logic into another place and then it worked.